# Turning off src path insert in Aptana Studio

Tags: aptana, aptana3

In Aptana Studio, if you type out `<img src="`... it tries to help you by looking up what's available in the relative path and auto-completing it in the src attribute.

I've looked through preferences and can't for the life of me figure out how to turn this off. How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

There is no preference to turn it off. However, if you'd like to be able to do so, please file a feature request at http://jira.appcelerator.org.